# How to check if in a string of words all the words start with the same letter

Tags: python

With a list like: `'apple,and,as'`
All the words start with the same letter. If this is the case, I would like to return true and if not return false.
How can I do that?
A is just the example!! I need to check if the words begin in every random same letter

I'm a Beginner.

Comment: Are all the words in a list? Can you add some sample code? Try to create a [mre]. In other words, help us help you.

Comment: No just a string  ex=‘apple, and,as’

Comment: To be blunt, being a "beginner" is not an excuse to be lazy. Quite the contrary. Have you tried to do any research on your own?

Comment: Yes i did, and I couldn’t find any

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string into a list, then use a list comprehension to check if each word starts with `'a'`. Then use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function on the resulting list to see if they're all `True`.

```
words = 'apple,and,as'
print(all([word.startswith('a') for word in words.split(',')]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the first letter of each word in a set. If the size of the set is 1 return True else False.

Hope this helps. :)

```
words = ['apple', 'and', 'as', 'apricot']

def function():
    firstLetters = set()
    for word in words:
        firstLetters.add(word[0])
    return len(firstLetters) == 1

result = function()
print("True") if result == True else print("False")
```